Key access to menu bar with ownerdraw
Since I use ownerdraw for the menu bar, the key access does not work anymore. Without ownerdraw Alt+F works for the item "&File", with ownerdraw nothing happens. What is missing here? When I process WM_MENUSELECT, wParam gives no information.
Menu creation:
HMENU hm;
HMENU winmenu = CreateMenu ();

MENUINFO mi;
mi.cbSize = sizeof (mi);
mi.fMask = MIM_BACKGROUND;
mi.hbrBack = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush (RGB (70, 70, 70));
SetMenuInfo (winmenu, &mi);
UINT barFlags = MF_POPUP|MF_OWNERDRAW;

hm = CreatePopupMenu ();
AppendMenuW (winmenu, barFlags, (UINT)hm, L"&File");
AppendMenuW (hm, MF_STRING, IDM_OPENFILE, L"&Open");
...

SetMenu (hwnd, winmenu);
DrawMenuBar (hwnd);

Ownerdraw processing:
case WM_MEASUREITEM:
{
    LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmi = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
    HDC hdc = GetDC (hwnd);
    SIZE size;
    GetTextExtentPoint32W (hdc, (PWCHAR)lpmi->itemData, wcslen ((PWCHAR)lpmi->itemData), &size);
    lpmi->itemWidth = size.cx;
    lpmi->itemHeight = size.cy;
    ReleaseDC (hwnd, hdc);
    break;
}
case WM_DRAWITEM:
{
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (lpdis->CtlType == ODT_MENU)
    {
        HDC hdc = lpdis->hDC;
        HPEN oldPen = (HPEN) SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject (DC_PEN));
        HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH) SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject (DC_BRUSH));
        SetBkMode (hdc, TRANSPARENT);

        if ((lpdis->itemState & ODS_HOTLIGHT) || (lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED))
        {
            SetDCPenColor (hdc, RGB (70, 20, 20));
            SetDCBrushColor (hdc, RGB (70, 20, 20));
            SetTextColor (hdc, RGB (255, 255, 255));
        }
        else
        {
            SetDCPenColor (hdc, RGB (70, 70, 70));
            SetDCBrushColor (hdc, RGB (70, 70, 70));
            SetTextColor (hdc, RGB (255, 255, 255));
        }
        Rectangle (hdc, lpdis->rcItem.left, lpdis->rcItem.top, lpdis->rcItem.right, lpdis->rcItem.bottom);
        DrawTextW (hdc, (PWCHAR)lpdis->itemData, -1, &lpdis->rcItem,
            ((lpdis->itemState & ODS_NOACCEL) ? DT_HIDEPREFIX : 0)
            |DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER);

        SelectObject (hdc, oldPen);
        SelectObject (hdc, oldBrush);
    }
    break;
}


Per MSDN documentation:
Owner-Drawn Menus and the WM_MENUCHAR Message

Menus other than owner-drawn menus can specify a menu mnemonic by inserting an underscore next to a character in the menu string. This allows the user to select the menu by pressing ALT and pressing the menu mnemonic character. In owner-drawn menus, however, you cannot specify a menu mnemonic in this manner. Instead, your application must process the WM_MENUCHAR message to provide owner-drawn menus with menu mnemonics.


Thank you for the hint. I tried WM_MENUCHAR before, but with no success. Finally it works now. I'll add the code to the question.

"Finally it works now. I'll add the code to the question." - that is not necessary. If you want to share your solution, you can post it as an answer instead.

System asks if I'm sure to answer my question. But yes I want to share it. For me it took days to find how ownerdrawn menus work - including item width, hiding accel key underline, accelerator processing. This post collects nearly the complete ownerdraw procedure then. Only thing missing for me is how to get rid of the white line below the menu. I'll address this in another question.

@Mapeman you can certainly answer your own question to share information.

If anyone has the same problem: this is how I solved it. In my app only the menu bar is ownerdrawn, the popups are done by the system.
case WM_MENUCHAR:
    {
        HMENU hmenu = (HMENU)lParam;
        WORD w;
        PWCHAR amp;
        MENUITEMINFO mi;
        for (w = 0; w < GetMenuItemCount (hmenu); w++)
        {
            mi.cbSize = sizeof (MENUITEMINFO);
            mi.fMask = MIIM_DATA;
            if (!GetMenuItemInfo (hmenu, w, TRUE, &mi))
                break;
            if ((amp = wcschr ((PWCHAR)mi.dwItemData, L'&')) != NULL)
                if (tolower (amp[1]) == tolower (LOWORD (wParam)))
                    return MAKELRESULT (w, 2);
        }
        break;
    }

